# How to substitute the column values with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL Workbench to get the table I am looking for. I am almost there. Here is the result of the query:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
employee.manager_id | employee.id | employee.first_name | employee.last_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
null                |     1       | Petra               | Wallace
null                |     3       | Peter               | Willis
null                |     5       | Michael             | Best
1                   |     2       | David               | Lone
3                   |     4       | Barbara             | Grinder
5                   |     6       | Anthony             | Krone
```

Now, I want to replace the values of the column `employee.manager_id` with the following:

- When the value is `null`, either leave it `null` or substitute it with the string "none"
- When the value has a number, it references the number of the `employee.id`. For example, the value 1 in `employee.manager_id` represents `employee.id` number 1, who is `Petra Wallace`.

I would like to show in the `employee.manager_id` column, the `employee.first_name` and the `employee.last_name`, instead of a number. Anybody has any idea how to do it?

Comment: show the query. You will need a self-left-join to get employee/manager relations fill in names. [COALESCE(field,"none")](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for substitution.

Comment: The query is ```SELECT employee.manager_id, employee.id, employee.first_name, employee.last_name
FROM  employee
ORDER BY employee.manager_id;```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN employee.manager_id IS NULL THEN "NONE"
    ELSE (SELECT CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name), e.id FROM employee e 
        WHERE e.id = employee.manager_id)
    END AS case_generated_column,
employee.id, employee.first_name, employee.last_name FROM employee ORDER BY employee.manager_id;
```

Comment: I tried your query. In the case when `employee.manager_id` is `null` it shows "none", but the rows that have a number in the `employee.manager_id` show `null` instead of the manager's name.

Comment: I edited my answer. Added table alias. Could you please let me know if it's working or not?

Answer (score 0):

A left join retrieves a manager based on the JOIN criteria. If there isn't a manager, then all of the `manager.*` fields are `NULL`.

```
SELECT 
       COALESCE(manager.first_name,"none") as manager_first_name,
       manager.last_name as manager_last_name,
       employee.id,
       employee.first_name,
       employee.last_name
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN employee manager
       ON employee.manager_id = manager.id 
ORDER BY employee.manager_id
```

Comment: Your query works beautifully!. Thank you very much!.